# Battery pack for high burst currents

Tags: batteries, high-current

I need to make a battery pack for a robot horse that has 4 x 12V geared DC motors turning wheels on the four hooves.

Here are the power draws:
5V systems:
Rasperry Pi (3 amp)
Aruduino Uno (<1 amp)
6 high-torque servos (up to 1amp each if they all moved at once)

12V systems:
4 [DC motors](https://www.surpluscenter.com/Electric-Motors/DC-Gearmotors/DC-Gearmotors/500-RPM-12-Volt-DC-Right-Angle-Gearmotor-5-1816.axd) with stall currents of 22A each, assuming <4A continuous
3 nema 17 Stepper motors
Buck converter 12V --> 5V @ 10A

Summary:  12V supply needs to be able for short bursts to crank out 95-100A, but would normally draw 21A while moving and about 2 amps while stationary.

Battery life of 15 min of hard use is sufficent

My first thought is to use 2-4 5AH 12V Sla batteries in parallel.  (Weight/size is not a factor, easy to charge, safe, and I have several lying around.)  I haven't been able to confirm their ability to put out bursts of current, but assume so since they are used for starter batteries on small engines.

Alternatively, I could use a 4S LiPo pack or 4x18650 cells.  Higher performance, but would make charging and monitoring more painful.  Costs 2-3X SLA batteries and adds a safety risk of battery fires.

Would 12V SLA batteries work for this, or do I need to plan on LiPo packs?  Or is there another better alternative for a battery pack?

Comment: raspberry pi 5V@3A... really?

Comment: Consider incorporating supercapacitors in your power supply to accommodate current bursts.

Comment: @vicatcu That's the spec for RPi 4.  I don't mind over-designing the 5V rail to make sure the RPi never browns out even if the 12V source has a huge current draw.